# Reference request: history of models and equations?

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, history

I am looking for an **in-depth** self-contained text for the layman which covers the historic development of major questions in physics and the models and equations considered to answer them, and their context of justification.

I have been able to find a few books about the history of science and physics that seem decent, but I feel they are more soft textual versions of a descriptive timeline, as opposed to an in-depth analysis type book. For example, I once read a paper about the detection of gravitional waves in the 60s and 70s, and it gave an interesting account of how turbulent the entire ordeal was, of how the experiments were judged, and of how ultimately consensus was reached partly due to many non-scientific factors. That's the sort of read I am interested in, but on a more general scale, a read that shows the behind-the-scenes action, as opposed to merely talking about the aftermath.

Comment: I think you are making a tall order : in-depth, self-contained, for the laymen, and encompassing the historical development of the major questions in physics and the models and equations - ie around 300-600 years of history.  That's not just the physics we have in our textbooks today (my A-level textbook was almost 1000 pages) but all of the blind alleys too.

Comment: @CuriousOne First of all, the date of the actual detection of gravity waves is irrelevant. Please understand that I am talking about ATTEMPTS to detect them. That's what an experiment IS. Secondly, I don't understand your second statement. You mean to say that consensus cannot possibly be reached (partly) non-scientifically? That statement is in contradiction to most of history, to most of freaking everyday life. Please educate yourself. The debacle of Weber's detection of gravity waves is a start.

Comment: @sammygerbil I disagree. Being a layman, surely my definition of the word "major" differs greatly from yours. I am not looking for a detailed account of each and every little equation that you deem "major", but merely a detailed account of the development of a *handful*of "major" models and even more generally, entire **fields** of physics, those that we the laymen already are vaguely aware of, or heard of. I believe such an account could be given in a a lengthy textbook or two. If I am mistaken of this as well, well then that's an answer to my question, and some good have come out of this.

Comment: @Jin: The data of detection is certainly relevant to those who detected them and it will be highly relevant to the Nobel Price committee. As for the "tumultuous" history of gravitational waves, that's pretty much an overstatement by the author of the piece that you have read, but that is nothing unusual. Science, when presented the way it actually happened, is mostly as boring as watching paint dry, so non-scientific authors like to construct Hollywood-esque stories of intrigue and betrayal around it. Don't buy them. That Weber's experiments couldn't work was always pretty obvious.

Comment: @CuriousOne Oh my, this is ridiculous. **It is not relevant to my question**.  I never claimed that gravity waves were proven to be detected in the 60s.  In regards to your criticism of a paper that you haven't even read, I am certainly interested to hear *why* Weber's experiments "couldn't work", "pretty obviously". Such an account would actually be an acceptable answer to my original question! Yet, sadly, it seems you are more interested in bickering over nonsense or attempting to force upon me your view of the world by ordering me to not "buy them", as if I should just buy what you say.

Comment: By the way, here's a curiosity for the curious one: rereading the mentioned paper, it includes statements made by a group of scientists criticizing Weber's experiement. They too happen to say the words "I don't buy it", and they too fail to substantiate that claim  with something more than lack of reproducibility or some vague distrust of Weber's experiment, one which he had decades of xperience with as opposed to the scientists criticizing it. Remind you of someone? And on the topic of "buying": I have bought nothing. That's why I am interested in this stuff and want to learn more.

Comment: @Jin: Whenever I read _anything_ about the history of science that is anything but bone dry I have to laugh about it... most of it is made up. If you have been part of actual scientific experiments, you will know what I am talking about, if not, it's almost impossible to explain. As for Weber's experiments, there is nothing wrong with them but one thing: lack of US\$. They were conducted on a small scale that simply didn't leave any chance of success. Let me know when you can find a couple of billion US$ to repeat them on the right scale and I will find you the team to spend the money. :-)

Comment: Hmmm ... I have to say that the race for $\theta_{13}$ was a source of tension bordering on excitement for me.; but I was on one of the competing experiments. On the flip side, it's not even a good anecdote at the bar during a convention, much less at a dinner party with non-specialists.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking far too much of one book, and your requirements are somewhat contradictory.  Books for the layman are not usually "in-depth."

It is up to you to define what you consider to be "major" and what topics you would like to read about.  If you do not do so, we can only guess.

Books on the detailed history of physics usually specialise in one era or topic, such as the scientific revolution, or electricity and magnetism.  For example, Stephen G Brush wrote about the historical development of the Kinetic Theory of Gases in the 19th century in "The Kind of Motion We Call Heat" (1976).  Steven Shapin and Simon Shaffer are other prominent authors in the history and sociology of science.

Detailed accounts, such as the paper you read, are usually memoirs or reviews appearing as relatively short articles in specialist scientific journals eg for particle physicists.  Another source is educational magazines such as "The Physics Teacher" published by the American Association of Physics Teachers, and "Physics Today" published by the American Institute of Physics.  Such articles are rarely collected together in books.

Popular books for the layman tend to avoid the development of ideas, models and equations, and the details of experiments.  Instead they concentrate on telling an exciting story.

The larger the book, and the more "in depth" it is, the more expensive it will be, with fewer copies printed, and the less chance of reprinting if those are sold out.  If the kind of book you want does exist, it is likely to be very difficult to get hold of.

Answer (score 0):

One book I'd definitely recommend is John Gribbin's *The Scientists*. While it is a little more biographical, it does include the trial and error, the buildup, etc., as well as the stories of quite a few more obscure scientists that contributed way more than you'd think. His book is also in a narrative format, not an encyclopedic format.

John Gribbin's book *The Search for Schrodinger's Cat* is more scientifically in-depth but it is limited to the development of quantum mechanics.

The first book is probably your best bet. Here it is [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812967887) (it has a book preview there).

Hope this helps!

Comment: These books,—while fun and a good source of inspiration for the aspiring youngster—certainly are not what the OP asked for. There are run of the mill pop-sci full of the usual misleading metaphors and misdirected focus on the things that seem strange instead of the tool of actual understanding.

Comment: @dmckee, I'm afraid I have to disagree with you. They are not misleading/misdirected; they were written by a scientist, for non-scientists, yes, but they were written accurately! Considering the OP's tall order, I think the books I mentioned are helpful.